# Vuejs usando una funcion computada para activar/desactivar boton (solo me lo checkea una vez, no siempre..)

Tags: vue.js

quiero hacer una funcion computada para desactivar/activar el boton de guardar/editar.

Como son varias condiciones: *Si el nombre no esta vacio... Si el titulo no.. etc..*... En vez de poner todo eso en la propiedad `:disabled` del boton me he creado una funcion computada :

```
 btnGuardarIsDisabled(){
                let isDisabled = true;
                if (
                    this.propuesta.titulo != null &&
                    this.propuesta.descripcion != null
                ) {
                    isDisabled = false;
                }
                else{
                    isDisabled = true;
                }

                return isDisabled;
            }
```

Basicamente estara disable cuando mi propuesta no este null en ninguno de sus campos (*titulo,descripcion..*)

Esta funcion la tengo puesta en mi boton del form:

```
 <div class="form-group">
         <button :disabled="btnGuardarIsDisabled" type="button" @click="click()" class="btn btn-primary">Crear</button>
 </div>
```

Mi form esta bindeado:

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Titulo:</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="titulo" placeholder="Titulo de la propuesta" required v-model="propuesta.titulo">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Descripción:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="descripcion" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Explica los mas detalladamente posible lo que pretendes hacer, que que necesitas y cuanto crees que podrias tardar." required v-model="propuesta.descripcion" ></textarea>
        </div>
```

Ahora, mi problema es que por defecto, como viene vacio lo desactiva, bien. Luego empiezo a rellenar mi form y una vez relleno esos campos que puse en mi condicion del computed se activa el boton, perfecto tambien. Pero si una vez activado borro uno de los campos no me lo vuelve a desactivar, es decir, una vez se activa ya no me lo desactiva.

Answer (score 0):

Ya he visto lo que pasaba, que estaba deficiendo en primera instancia los campos por defecto a null, pero y luego el computed tambien los comprobaba si eran null, ¿porque no es null si estan vacios (despues de haber escrito y borrado)? pues que realmente ya esos campos borrados son string vacios, no nulos. Asi que he sustituido los nullos por `''`